# How to convert a jpeg to an png with djpeg and pnmtopng?

Tags: bash, shell, image-conversion

The exercise is to convert an jpeg image to an png with djpeg and pnmtopng. The first step to convert it into an pnm works perfectly but pnmtopng doesnt work.

The first step works perfectly fine the program created an pnm file.
[Files]https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1vTn.png

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.jpeg; do
djpeg -pnm -outfile "$file".pnm  "$file"
pnmtopng  *.pnm
done
```

But the pnmtopng does something linke this and nothing happens 
[Terminal]https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnbgr.jpg
The perfect case would be an png file from this..

Comment: Try replacing all stuff in loop with `djpeg -pnm "$file" | pnmtopng > "$file.png"`

Comment: BTW I'd recommend to use `ImageMagick` rather than combining individual designated converters.

Comment: I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: It would be simpler with ImageMagick, I agree, but it's a much heavier weight installation. @tshiono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for file in *.jpeg; do
    djpeg -pnm "$file" | pnmtopng > "$file.png"
done
```

The issue with your existing code is that `pnmtopng` writes the PNG file on `stdout` which is the Terminal in your case, so I have redirected it to a file with `>`. Whilst redirecting input and output, we might as well do the same and have `jpeg` write on `stdout` and hook that into `pnmtopng` which can read from `stdin` - that way we don't need to write an intermediate PNM file to disk.

---

Or use **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick mogrify -format png *.jpeg
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this function but our professor wants that we use those 2 functions.